# Wordpress - Need to direct users after logging in to different pages (based on the link they clicked)

Tags: php, wordpress

Brace yourselves, this can get a little confusing. I have a wordpress website which currently directs users after logging in to their user dashboard. That functions exactly as we want it too on desktop and mobile/tablet devices.

Our website consists of different sections of course, to list a few examples we have 'Celeb News', 'Videos', 'Images', etc. Our website does not require logging in for any reason other than to 'Submit' content and have a 'Profile'.

Here's the DILEMMA. We have a Android app that is a wrapper of our website. In our APP we would like to force people to login in order to use the APP. We have limited functions in the platform we are creating this app with.

Here is how our URL structure is setup:
/wp-login.php
/wp-login.php?action=register

We want to be able to setup approx 5 different URLS that will direct the user to the desired page after logging in. I'm not a coder and the code I'm about to place below is wrong but I'm doing it for visual reasons for everyone to understand me better. We are looking for something like this:

https://example.com/wp-login.php?action=redirect_to"/index.php"
https://example.com/wp-login.php?action=redirect_to"/category/hottest/"

So we can place these links direclty on the buttons. When a user wants to access these sections on the app, they are asked to login. Once they login they are directed to the specified page or section. We also have cookies enabled in our login plugin so that if a user has logged in it will remember, we have our app setup so it can save these cookies to the devices. So we want the links to redirect the user to the desired page via the url if they are already logged in as well as the links on the buttons will be permanent.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you instead thought of marking these special pages as "members only" so that whoever comes to them, using any link out there, is automatically redirected to the login page first, if they are not already logged-in?

Comment: Well, having an account has it's own benefits like being able to submit videos, images, create memes, etc. So we do not want to restrict users who visit our website from accessing basic website categories by forcing them to register.

An app on the other hand is a little different, most apps request users login and it increases the apps userbase etc. So we need a way to keep it open to the website, mobile and tablet devices while capturing users on the app.

Now we do have the ability to insert code in our app and run a script if needed instead of the URL solution. We'd rather our option.

Answer (score 0):

All righty, so why not use the already built-in WordPress redirect, then?

If you build your login urls with the "redirect_to" parameter, the user should be automatically redirected once they have logged-in:

https://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=%2Findex%2Ephp

Notice that you will have to url-encode the redirect value. How you do that, exactly, will depend on the language you are using, etc...

But basically, as soon as the user successfully logs in, in this case, she will be redirected to /index.php

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried that approach and unfortunately it did not work for me. Just to clarify, the approach worked fine as it needed too, but for my situation it did not do the trick. I either need a direct way of doing it via the url or I need a way I can save 1 post in 2 categories but make that post available to everyone who views it from category a but require login if you'd like to see the same post in category b.

Comment: Sorry, the url way did not work. Because when you launch the APP, it preloads all the associated 'tabs'. Once ther user logs in on the first time, it does not refresh all tabs but only the tab he logged in on. So that means that when the user clicks on the next tab, they are still loaded with the 'unsigned' in user. So you can scratch out my comment above. The only way I can do it is to be able to do the second method I suggested. Here are pictures of my app so you have an idea of what I'm talking about.

Comment: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91zV7%2BYE7XL.png

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91g%2Bb9kxZUL.png

Comment: I see... Well you maybe could rely on the user-agent string, or even a special cookie, make it unique in your app, so that WP could detect this and require login for all (or some) pages using a filter in your WP theme... Of course user-agent strings can be forged, and cookies can be manually set, so that might not be super secure, but maybe that's "good enough" for your use case...